# Uploading a file on OneDrive Business from iOS App fails

Tags: ios, swift, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to upload a file from my app to OneDrive Business repository using graph API.

and I know there are two steps to do that...

1. Create upload session by calling - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/hello.docx:/createUploadSession` (this api call works fine)
2. Response of above API call be return a `URL` which I'm using to upload a file.

this is how I'm creating request for this API call -

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url)
request.timeoutInterval = TimeInterval(60)
request.httpMethod = "PUT"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")

uploadRequest.setValue("26", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
uploadRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
let contentLength = Int(file.contentLength) ?? 0;
uploadRequest.setValue("bytes 0-\(25)/\(contentLength)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Range");
```

Note upload is implemented using `URLSessionUploadTask` -

```
self.session.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, fromFile: self.fileUrl)
```

It start the upload and file gets uploaded 100% but at last update fails with response as below

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1c0a39420> { URL: https://indxyz-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ram_kapoor_indxyz_onmicrosoft_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01BSG3ERN6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/uploadSession%3Fguid='cb929739-8c1c-48b2-9be4-3dc1cd2aef09'&path='~tmp0F_hello.docx'&overwrite=True&rename=False&dc=0&tempauth=redacted }
 { Status Code: 400, Headers {
        "Content-Length" =     (
            0
        );
        Date =     (
            "Mon, 22 Oct 2018 10:46:09 GMT"
        );
        "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
            "max-age=31536000"
        );
        microsoftsharepointteamservices =     (
            "16.0.0.8210"
        );
        "ms-cv" =     (
            "nprY6jvwAHAoBWzVPpyQgQ.0"
        );
        p3p =     (
            "CP=\"ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI\""
        );
        "request-id" =     (
            "ead89a9e-f03b-7000-2805-6cd53e9c9081"
        );
        sprequestguid =     (
            "ead89a9e-f03b-7000-2805-6cd53e9c9081"
        );
        "x-content-type-options" =     (
            nosniff
        );
        "x-frame-options" =     (
            SAMEORIGIN
        );
        "x-ms-invokeapp" =     (
            "1; RequireReadOnly"
        );
        "x-msedge-ref" =     (
            "Ref A: A4A5ACB248D94992BD7B83645B01A952 Ref B: BOM01EDGE0220 Ref C: 2018-10-22T10:46:09Z"
        );
        "x-powered-by" =     (
            "ASP.NET"
        );
    } }
```

**My Android App is working fine as buffer size has been specified there -**
I thing this is something to do with buffer size as Microsoft has mentioned in the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online)

> **Upload bytes to the upload session**
>
> To upload the file, or a portion of the file, your app makes a PUT
>   request to the uploadUrl value received in the createUploadSession
>   response. You can upload the entire file, or split the file into
>   multiple byte ranges, as long as the maximum bytes in any given
>   request is less than 60 MiB.
>
> The fragments of the file must be uploaded sequentially in order.
>   Uploading fragments out of order will result in an error.
>
> Note: If your app splits a file into multiple byte ranges, the size of
>   each byte range MUST be a multiple of 320 KiB (327,680 bytes). Using a
>   fragment size that does not divide evenly by 320 KiB will result in
>   errors committing some files.

I'm not sure which part I'm wrong at and how to provide buffer size on session upload task in iOS.

Comment: Hi, @suryakant, do you have try to split the file into multiple?

Comment: @SeiyaSu thank you for responding. Can you elaborate your approach little more?

Comment: Do you have the response body available? That would hopefully give some details as to what is causing the `400` response.

Comment: @Brad I'm able to achieve desired result using approach mention here -  github.com/jthake-msft/OneDrive-iOS-Swift-LargeFileUploader

Comment: @Brad BTW with this approach I'm unable to upload file in background. Any suggestion??